# Google analytics does not show statistics and looks different

Tags: magento, google-analytics, magento2, google-analytics-4

I created a new application and noticed that it was different from my first one.
I have 2 sites on the Magento 2 platform. I want to separately collect data about them.

I had previously created a store for analytics in which I could create views. There I took the Account Number starting with the UK and added it to the settings.

But now I am trying to create a new tracking application and I get a different type of application in which I cannot create views, what am I doing wrong?
How can I connect it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmdEg.png]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new Property in Google Analytics you can find Universal Analytics type Property by clicking on Show advanced options:

[image]

So you can obtain and use its ID (UA-XXXXX-X).